# AWS Lambda: How to achieve "only once" execution

Tags: callback, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda function, per documentation, timeouts in max 60 seconds. If it hits the timeout, it considers it as error and fires again. I would like to prevent the subsequent firing. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I've never experienced that a function is fired again after a timeout. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list

> Functions that exceed any of the limits listed in the previous limits tables will fail with an exceeded limits exception.

How did you invoke your function? If I manually invoke a long running function I get this error message:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Task timed out after 60.00 seconds"
}
```